# ALTERA UART communication

Tags: uart, intel-fpga, quartus, jtag, nios

I would like to use the Altera DE1_soc board to make serial communications from my PC to teratem.
JTAG uart intel FPGA IP seems to be available only on internal NIOS console instead of terterm.
I do not know which JTAG and UART to choose from the platform designer.
I would like to get help if you know.

Comment: Where do you want to instantiate the UART? Is it used by your NIOS processor or is it to have access to a component in the FPGA (implemented in vhdl or verilog=

Comment: Thank you for answer. I add RS232 in platform designer. so, I resolved the problem. Thank you!